# How do I create a thread in discord with my c# discord bot

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord

i want to create threads in discord using my discord bot.
Here is the documentation: https://discordnet.dev/guides/introduction/intro.html
The git Repository from the nuget can be found here: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net

Do you have any ideas how to start a thread?
I already figured out, that there are 2 potential classes that could be used:

- RestThreadChannel
- SocketThreadChannel

I already saw examples with a message to create a thread based on the message.

All I want to do is to create a private (Discord-)Thread (with Discord-Nitro) when a Button is pressed. The Buttonevent works fine, I only need an opportunity to create a Thread.

Any Help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/threads

Comment: here you go: https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.Rest.RestTextChannel.html#Discord_Rest_RestTextChannel_CreateThreadAsync_System_String_Discord_ThreadType_Discord_ThreadArchiveDuration_Discord_IMessage_System_Nullable_System_Boolean__System_Nullable_System_Int32__Discord_RequestOptions_

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Your Comment helped Alex but if I try to create a RestThreadChannel via the constructor it says:"Cannot acces internal constructor here". How do I create an instance of it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was checking out some functions and I found out how to do it.

```cs
SocketTextChannel.CreateThreadAsync(variables)
```

You are able to attach a message to the thread in variables.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem too! I'm going to assume you're after one of these three (likely) scenarios. Following the [interaction framework](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/samples/InteractionFramework) example, here are some samples of creating a new thread in either a specific channel, the current context channel, or from user input.

Scenario 1: User selects channel where new thread goes.

```cs
public async Task NewThreadInPickedChannelAsync(ITextChannel channel)
        {
            var newThread = await channel.CreateThreadAsync(
                name: "test", 
                autoArchiveDuration: ThreadArchiveDuration.OneHour,
                invitable: false,
                type: ThreadType.PublicThread,
            );
            await newThread.SendMessageAsync("Thread test message");
            await RespondAsync(text: $"Created thread");   
        }
```

Scenario 2: New thread is created in channel they sent command from.

```cs
public async Task NewThreadInCurrentChannelAsync()
        {
            ulong channelId = Context.Channel.Id;
            var channel = Context.Channel as ITextChannel;
            var newThread = await channel.CreateThreadAsync(
                name: "test", 
                autoArchiveDuration: ThreadArchiveDuration.OneHour,
                invitable: false,
                type: ThreadType.PublicThread
            );
            await newThread.SendMessageAsync("Thread test message");
            await RespondAsync(text: $"Created thread");   
        }
```

Scenario 3: Thread is created in a specific channel using its channel id.

```cs
public async Task NewThreadInSpecificChannelAsync()
        {
            ulong channelId = Convert.ToUInt64(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_CHANNEL_ID"));
            var channel = Context.Guild.GetChannel(channelId) as ITextChannel;
            var newThread = await channel.CreateThreadAsync(
                name: "test", 
                autoArchiveDuration: ThreadArchiveDuration.OneHour,
                invitable: false,
                type: ThreadType.PublicThread
            );
            await newThread.SendMessageAsync("Thread test message");
            await RespondAsync(text: $"Created thread");   
        }
```

Hope this helps. That should be it!